# Ignoring fractions can lead to correct answer

Tags: equation-solving, recreational-mathematics

There is a curious example in Posamentier's book "Magnificent Mistakes in Mathematics" (p. 72):
$(7+3/7)*(4-3/13)= 7*4=28$, where cancelling the fractions leads to correct result. If we generalize
$(a+b/c)*(x-y/z)=a*x$, for which (integer) six-tuples does this "calculation" hold (in the range, for example, from 1 to 10 for each number)?

I can not imagine a brute force method, and I tried with pencil and paper with no success. Can you help me please to resolve this question from recreational mathematics.

Comment: See Project Euler [Problem 33](https://projecteuler.net/problem=33) for an exercise in more curious fraction cancellations.

Answer (score 11):

To just find examples use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)

```
examples = FindInstance[{
    (a + b/c) (x - y/z) == a x,
    1 <= a <= 10, 1 <= b < c, 1 <= c <= 10, 1 <= x <= 10, 1 <= y < z, 
    1 <= z <= 10},
   {a, b, c, x, y, z}, Integers, 5];

HoldForm[(a + b/c) (x - y/z) == a x] /. examples
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
% // ReleaseHold

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

To find all solutions

```
sol = Solve[{
    (a + b/c) (x - y/z) == a x,
    1 <= a <= 10, 1 <= b <= 10, 1 <= c <= 10, 1 <= x <= 10, 1 <= y <= 10, 
    1 <= z <= 10,
    b < c, y < z},
   {a, b, c, x, y, z}, Integers];
```

The total number of solutions is

```
Length@sol

(* 1293 *)
```

Verifying,

```
And @@ ((a + b/c) (x - y/z) == a x /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may creat a loop over the variables a,b,..z from 1 to 10 and check if the condition is fulfilled. If yes you keep the current values. Otherwise you discard them:

```
res = Reap[
Do[
    If[(a + b/c) (x - y/z) == a  x, Sow@{a, b, c, x, y, z}]
    , {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
][[2,1]]
```

There are 8856 possible six-tuples.

Comment: For `b/c` and `y/z` to be proper fractions requires that `c > b` and `z > y`. This assumption would reduce the number of solutions to `1293`.

Comment: Hello Bob and Daniel, thanks for answer (it was night between in Europe :) ). I just like such problems, but my knowledge of Mathematica stopped around version 3.0 :(, so expect more questions, regards and respect to you - experts!

Answer (score 1):

We want
$$\left(a+\frac{b}{c}\right)\left(x-\frac{y}{z}\right)=a x$$
which means
$$b y+a c y-b x z=0$$
which we can solve for $x$ as
$$x=\frac{b y+ a c y}{b z}$$

The task now becomes finding set of five-tuples $(a,b,c,y,z)$ such that $\frac{b y+ a c y}{b z}$ is an integer number and we have the constraints $b\le c-1$ and $y\le z-1$ as any integer part of the fractions $b/c$ and $y/z$ can be absorbed into $a$ and $x$.

For $a,b,c,y,z=1,\dots,20$ we do have 32961 proper solutions, which my 2015 Macbook with 2 cores finds in 2.3 seconds. The code is

```
results = With[{k = 20},
Select[IntegerQ[#[[4]]] &]@
 Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, (b y + a c y)/(b z), y, z}, {a, k}, {c, 
    k}, {b, c - 1}, {z, k}, {y, z - 1}], 4]
]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.3, Null} *)
```

As examples:

```
HoldForm[(a + b/c) (x - y/z)] /. Table[
  Thread[{a, b, c, x, y, z} -> results[[i]]], {i, {456, 4956, 32961}}
]
(* {(1+1/11) (6-4/8),(4+2/6) (12-12/13),(20+18/20) (22-18/19)} *)
```

where the results are integers as designed:

```
% // ReleaseHold
(* {6, 48, 440} *)
```

---

One can technically increase the efficiency by noting that the pairs $(b,c)$ and $(y,z)$ are defined only upto an overall scaling, i.e. $(x,y)\sim (\lambda x,\lambda y)$ for integer $\lambda$. Hence we can restrict the search for integers $(b,c)$ which are *coprime*, and similarly for $(y,z)$. In other words, we can first generate all coprimes within a certain range and then use them instead. For the integers in the range $1\cdots 30$, we run

```
results = With[{k = 30},
With[{
  pairs = 
   Select[CoprimeQ @@ # &]@
    Flatten[Table[{j, i}, {i, k}, {j, i - 1}], 1]
  },
 Select[IntegerQ[#[[4]]] &]@Flatten[Table[
    With[{b = p1[[1]], c = p1[[2]], y = p2[[1]], z = p2[[2]]},
     {a, b, c, (b y + a c y)/(b z), y, z}
     ], {a, k}, {p1, pairs}, {p2, pairs}], 2]
 ]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {35., Null} *)

results // Length
(* 34406 *)
```

As an example, we see that

```
HoldForm[(a + b/c) (x - y/z)] /. Thread[{a, b, c, x, y, z} -> results[[-1]]]
(* (30+1/30) (848-16/17) *)
```

which is

```
% // ReleaseHold
(* 25440 *)
```

---

One can also generate examples of larger numbers using `FindInstance` command, as suggested by others. In terms of our equations, it reads as

```
FindInstance[b y + a c y - b x z == 0 && c > b && z > y 
 && a > 10000, {a, b, c, x, y, z}, PositiveIntegers, 3]
(* {{a -> 10247, b -> 1, c -> 42, x -> 11, y -> 1, z -> 39125}, {a -> 10247, b -> 1, c -> 42, x -> 11, y -> 71, z -> 2777875}, {a -> 11414, b -> 1, c -> 23, x -> 2, y -> 44, z -> 5775506}} *)
```

which gives

```
HoldForm[(a + b/c) (x - y/z)] /. %
(* {(10247+1/42) (11-1/39125),(10247+1/42) (11-71/2777875),(11414+1/23) (2-44/5775506)} *)
```

For example,
$$\left(11414+\frac{1}{23}\right)\left(2-\frac{44}{5775506}\right)=11414\times 2$$